External webcam (Nexigo) requires reboot every day for apps to use it on MacOS
I am using this Nexigo external webcam. Mostly, it works fine with Amazon Chime on MacOS 13.6.7. However, every day it doesn't work on the first attempt. Chime can recognize the webcam but can't use it. It gives error message "We are unable to connect to the camera you selected. Try unplugging and plugging in your webcam or restarting Amazon Chime."
Once I follow this instruction, the webcam starts working. I need to perform both operations (replugging and restarting Chime) for it to work. Just doing either doesn't work. I have similar experience with other applications that use camera like FaceTime where I need to replug it once.
Does any one have thoughts on what can be the issue here? Or any suggestions to automate this daily ritual? TIA!
